# Google Analytics session-scoped fields returning multiple values

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've discovered that there are certain GA "session" scoped fields in BigQuery that have multiple values for the same `fullVisitorId` and `visitId` fields. See the example below:

[image: example showing in the same session, the user has two different devices]

Grouping the fields doesn't help either. In GA, I've checked the number of users vs number of users split by different devices. The user count is different:

[image: users number mismatch in GA]

This explains what's going on, a user would be grouped under multiple devices. My conclusion is that at some point during the users session, their browser user-agent changes and in the subsequent hit, a new device type is set in GA.

I'd have hoped GA would use either the first or last value, to avoid this scenario, but I guess they don't. My question is, if I'm accepting this as a "flaw" in GA. I'd rather pick one value. What's the best way to select the last or first device value from the below query:

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  device.deviceCategory
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` desktop
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` mobile ) table
```

I've tried doing a sub-select and using `STRING_AGG()`, attempting to order by `hits.time` and limiting to one value and that still creates another row.

I've tested and found that the below fields all have the same issue:

```
visitNumber
totals.hits
totals.pageviews
totals.timeOnSite
trafficSource.campaign
trafficSource.medium
trafficSource.source
device.deviceCategory
totals.sessionQualityDim
channelGrouping
device.mobileDeviceInfo
device.mobileDeviceMarketingName
device.mobileDeviceModel
device.mobileInputSelector
device.mobileDeviceBranding
```

**UPDATE**

See below queries around this particular `fullVisitorId` and `visitId` - UNION has been removed:

`visitStartTime` added:
[image: visitStartTime added]

`visitStartTime` and `hits.time` added:
[image: visitStartTime and hits.time added]

Comment: There's a solution here for you...

Answer (score 2):

Well, from the looks of things, I think you have 3 options:

1 - Group by fullVisitorId, visitId; and use Max or MIN deviceCategory.  That should prevent a device switcher from being double-counted,  It's kind of arbitrary but then so is the GA data.

2 -  Option two is similar but, if the deviceCategory result can be anything (i.e. isn't constrained in the results to just the valid deviceCategory members), you can use a CASE to check MAX(deviceCategory) = MIN(deviceCategory) and if they are different, return 'Multiple Devices'

3 - You could go further, counting the number of different devices used, construct a concatenation that lists them in some way, etc.

I'm going to write up Number 2 for you.  In your question, you have 2 different queries: one with [date] and one without - I'll provide both.

Without [date]:

```
SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    case when max(device.deviceCategory) = min(device.deviceCategory) 
       then max(device.deviceCategory) 
       else 'Multiple Devices' 
    end as deviceCategory,
    {metric aggregations here}
FROM 
    (SELECT *
        FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` desktop
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` mobile 
    ) table
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId
```

With [date]:

```
SELECT
    [date],
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    case when max(device.deviceCategory) = min(device.deviceCategory) 
       then max(device.deviceCategory) 
       else 'Multiple Devices' 
    end as deviceCategory,
    {metric aggregations here}
FROM 
    (SELECT *
        FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` desktop
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` mobile 
    ) table
GROUP BY [date], fullVisitorId, visitId
```

I'm assuming here that the Selects and Union that you gave are sound.

**Also**, I should point out that those {metric aggregations} should be something other than SUMs, otherwise you will still be double-counting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is helpful, thank you. I will definetly use it for some of the other fields that behave like this. Looking into device.deviceCategoery further, I found that when I also include "hits.time" (timestamp - hit level field), the users device changes. I would ideally want to be able to show the first one based on their first hit in that session or last.

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi - ...and don't forget to 'Accept' it if the answer works for you.  Thanks.

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi - I added a note about the metric aggregations.  Don't forget to 'Accept' the answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi - I made a few additions to your Google Analytics solution since your last message.  You should take a look - and don't forget to 'Accept' the answer if it helped you out.  Thanks.

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi - Just wondering if you have tried this solution since I made all the additions to it.  I hope it worked for you.  If it did, don't forget to 'Accept' it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I’m currently in talks with google support on this issue. If you were to look at Martin’s response below you will see why this shouldn’t be occurring. When I have more details from Google, I’ll proceed accordingly

Comment: @MeisamEbrahimi - Doesn't function as a work-around in the meantime?  It should eliminate the double-counting even when devices are included.

Comment: the workaround is something that I had come up with anyway, I was trying to get to the bottom of why it’s happening in the first place. If I were to use a workaround, we still don’t have a choice on the device. It’s randomly picked

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not possible to have two values for one row in this field, because it can only contain one value.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. you're actually querying two separate datasets/ two different views - that's not clearly visible with the example code. Client id (=fullvisitorid) is only unique per Property (Tracking Id, the UA-xxxxx stuff). If you query two different views from different properties you have to expect to get same ids used twice.
2. Given they are coming from one property, these two rows could actually be one session on a midnight split, which means visitId stays the same, but visitStartTime changes. But that would also mean the decision algorithm for device type changed in the meantime ... that would be curious.

Try using visitStartTime and see what happens.
If you're using two different properties use a user id to combine or separate the sessions by adding a constant - you can't combine them.
`SELECT 'property_A' AS constant FROM ...`

hth

Comment: please see my updated post above - I removed the UNION as that had no relevance to this issue, it's only coming from one view. It seems that visitStartTime and hits.time is duplicated for each device

Comment: Also, I completely agree with you, this shouldn't be happening at all. The whole idea of a session is to have one value for this field type in the row.

I've added columns to see if there's anyway to distinguish these rows, I've found nothing. I even added hit scoped custom dimensions and even then for each value both tablet and mobile appear. This has me completely baffled and I suspect there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: Is it a roll-up property maybe?

Comment: Sorry, this was wrong, it's not a roll-up property, it has been linked to a roll-up property. In BigQuery, the querying is done on this property, which is not a roll-up property.

Comment: Now I'm out of ideas :) I would contact support at this time.

Comment: I will do so, thank you for all your help. Hopefully, there will be an answer to this, I'll post it here once I have something